# Shortest way to invoke a method with parameters in C#

Tags: c#

When I need to invoke some code in the specified thread, i am using something like this:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

delegate void MethodToInvokeDelegate(string foo, int bar);

void MethodToInvoke(string foo, int bar)
{
    DoSomeWork(foo);
    DoMoreWork(bar); 
}

void SomeMethod()
{
    string S = "Some text";
    int I = 1;
    dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new MethodToInvokeDelegate(MethodToInvoke), new object[] {S, I});
}
```

This code works fine, but it's quite heavy. I'd like to make it without declaring `MethodToInvoke` and `MethodToInvokeDelegate` - using an anonymous method. But I can't figure out how to pass parameters to it.

I can't write this like:

```
dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate() { DoSomeWork(S); DoMoreWork(I); });
```

I need to actually pass parameters to method.

Is it any way to write it short and simple?

Example:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
int[] ArrayToFill = new int[3];

void SomeMethod()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        dispatcher.BeginInvoke( { ArrayToFill[i] = 10; } );
}
```

This code will not work: method will be called with i = 1, 2, 3 and will raise IndexOutOfRange exception. `i` will be incremented before method begins to execute. So we need to rewrite it like:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
int[] ArrayToFill = new int[3];

delegate void MethodToInvokeDelegate(int i);

void MethodToInvoke(int i)
{
    ArrayToFill[i] = 10; 
}

void SomeMethod()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
         dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new MethodToInvokeDelegate(MethodToInvoke), new object[] {i});
}
```

Comment: Shortest way is `method_name();`

Comment: @un-lucky That would run it synchronously, but the use of `BeginInvoke()` indicates that it should be run asynchronously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you wish to avoid creating a delegate type for each call, make use of `Action<>`, `Action<,>`, etc

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
string S = "Some text";
int I = 1;
dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                        (Action<string, int>)((foo, bar) =>
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(bar.ToString(), foo);
                            //DoSomeWork(foo);
                            //DoMoreWork(bar); 
                        }), 
                        new object[] { S, I }
                      );
```

---

an example with `ArrayToFill[j] = 10;` action can be fixed very simple:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    // lambda captures int variable
    // use a new variable j for each lambda to avoid exceptions
    dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        ArrayToFill[j] = 10;
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string S = "Some text";
int I = 1;

dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    DoSomeWork(S);
    DoMoreWork(I);
}));
```

[EDIT]

In response to your modified question:

The issue you are seeing there is [modified closure problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/).

To fix it, you merely need to copy the argument before invoking the method:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

int[] ArrayToFill = new int[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    int index = i;
    dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { ArrayToFill[index] = 10; } ));
}
```

Comment: It's still the same as `dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate() { DoSomeWork(S); DoMoreWork(I); });`

Comment: @AndrewR And you can pass parameters to it... Can you more clearly explain what you mean by `I need to actually pass parameters to method`? In your answer, write the code how you'd like it to appear, including the context from which it is called. At the moment it is very unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: Added example to the question

Answer (score 1):

```
yourUIcontrol.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
    //your code goes here
}));
```